# Python Turn Based Game, Can't Find A Way To Skip To Next Player

Tags: python

So I have simple project in Python. I have to makea simplified 2 person UNO game. I'm having a problem with the turns. I don't know why but player 2 can't paly the game. It always lets the first player to play. My code is basically like this:

```
Turn=1   
while (Turn>0): 
        if (Turn%2==1):
            #Player 1 plays a card
            else:
                #Player 1 draws a card
            Turn+=1
        if (Turn%2==0):
            #Player 2 plays a card
            else:
                #Player 2 draws a card
            Turn+=1
```

So what is the problem in code? How can I handle it? OR is there any suggestions for turn system?

Comment: Debug your code on the piece of paper, step by step, starting with `Turn=1`

Comment: Change the second `if` to `elif (Turn%2==0):`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are increasing Turn by 1 and then again checking if `Turn%2==0` in that iteration itself. For example if Turn is 1 currently, it will go in first if loop and then it will get incremented to become 2. Now it will pass the condition of second if loop too, and again will be incremented. You should put `Turn+=1` at the end of all blocks as it is duplicated in both blocks.

```
Turn=1   
while (Turn>0): 
        if (Turn%2==1):
            # Player 1 plays or draws the card

        else:  #Notice here
            # Player 2 plays or draws the card.
        Turn+=1
```